# How to find an optimum location point on a line?

Tags: c, geometry

A line is given and a bunch of points are given. I have to find a point on line for which sum of distances from given points is minimum. **I could't find any algorithm to implement in c**. Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a classical *minimization problem*. You should learn about it.

Comment: Start by finding the rectangle that encloses all of the points. That gives you an approximate search range for X and Y.

Comment: @user3386109 This rectangle won't necessarily even contain any part of the line.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yup, that's true. My hint was to ignore to line for the moment and think about what useful properties the collection of points may have.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have rotated the line clockwise by its slope. So now all the points have also changed to (cos(-theta),sin(-theta)) multiplied by their original value. Then I took all the _changed x coordinates_ and took their mean. I am considering that point to be optimum point. Calculating distance from that point. and rotating anticlockwise with **theta** angle again to get the original coordinate values on the line.

Answer (score 5):

Without  loss of generality, the line is the X axis (otherwise rotate the whole geometry). Then you want to minimize

```
Sum √[(X - Xk)² + Yk²]
```

which you can do by canceling the first derivative

```
Sum (X - Xk)/√[(X - Xk)² + Yk²] = 0
```

Unfortunately, this is a nonlinear equation that will require numerical methods.

As a starting approximation, you can use the minimizer of the sum of the squared distances,

```
Sum [(X - Xk)² + Yk²]
```

by solving

```
Sum (X - Xk) = 0
```

which simply gives the point `(X*, 0)` where `X*` is the average abscissa.

Comment: As long as none of the given points are on the line, using Newton-Raphson on this seems to work well. However if some of the points are on the line then the objective is not differentiable (at these points) and things are not so nice.